# My painting fence code is not giving correct output for large input

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

```c
long long countWays(int n, int k){
        // code here
        if(n==1) return k;
        long long a[n-1];
        long long b[n-1];
        // for n=2
        a[0]=k;
        b[0]=k*(k-1);
        for(int i=1;i<n-1;i++){
            a[i] = b[i-1]%1000000007;
            b[i] = ((a[i-1] + b[i-1])*(k-1))%1000000007;
        }
        return (a[n-2] + b[n-2]) %1000000007;
    }
```

This is my code to solve the 'painting fence' problem. For most of the input it gave the correct out put. But for the input `27608` `99118` the output is `340817251` instead of `108753863`. Why?

I changed the datatypes of arrays from int to long long to store large numbers.

Breakdown
`b[i] = ((a[i-1] + b[i-1])*(k-1))%1000000007`
this line to separate addition and multiplication, so to manage the large results.

Checked with (long long)(k*k-1). But the answer is not equal to the correct one.

Comment: Do you believe that all are familiar with `painting fence` problem exact formulation?

Comment: Curiously a question about this problem was asked 1 day ago and it had exactly the same bug on exactly the same test-case as yours (namely `k*(k-1)` overflows a 32 bit int).

Comment: Your answer suggests you "checked with" `(long long)(k*k-1)`, but that doesn't fix the overflow problem -- the cast to `long long` comes after the overflow.